# pyspark paramether type of MultilayerPerceptronClassifier

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to use spark with python, and I need to perform binary classification. After some research(I'm new to spark) I find MultilayerPerceptronClassifier but I don't understand some things.

Witch kind of Type must be the labelCol and the featuresCol? can be a simple integer(0 or 1) and a vector(the output of a VectorAssembler)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PySpark takes your feature columns and generates a single column containing a vector of features. And label column is the target variable which is binary in your case.

Here is an example of how the vector assembler works.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

# Input data frame consists of four columns id, hour, mobile, clicked.
dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 18, 1.0, , 1.0)],
    ["id", "hour", "mobile", "clicked"])

# We take the first two features hour and mobile and create a vector of features.
# This column is named "features".
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["hour", "mobile"],
    outputCol="features")

# We use the VectorAssembler assembler to transform our dataset into an  
# "data" data frame which is the same as dataset but with an additional column
# "features.
data = assembler.transform(dataset)
```

After this step, you can apply your prediction models.